# Should you delegate print to a thread pool executor while an event loop is running?

Tags: python

Once an event loop has started running, nothing should perform a blocking operation without delegating it to an executor.

Should I delegate prints to an executor?

Comment: Seems the answer of your question is in your question itself. What is your actual issue?

Comment: Where does the assertion you give in your first sentence come from? Does the logic it asserts apply to the code you would delegate to as well as your original code? If so, then nothing can ever do a blocking operation, they'll delegate to each other forever. I'm also not sure I'd think `print` would block, but I suppose it might if you're printing to a pipe or something (but that would be unusual).

Comment: Why does not print block exactly? Isn't it an I/O operation? That is why I asked the question.

Comment: Not all I/O is equal in terms of how long it takes. In most cases, print is copying the printed string from one buffer in memory to another buffer in memory.

Comment: I suppose `print` is indeed blocking, and might be slower than a lot of other opterations. But at some level *every* operation (even adding numbers) is blocking for at least a small amount of time. I think how sensitive you are to short blocking operations depends on how "hot" the calling code is. You probably don't want to be printing from the inside of a very tight loop, though pushing that out into a thread pool executor isn't really going to *solve* that problem, since the tight loop will just build up a massive backlog of pending prints that need to get finished at some point.